# Collapse columns in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel

I am making a script to parse results from a database into Excel. I have both my rows and columns grouped. I have a method for folding the group (with the +/- button). I can collapse my rows via:

```
call: e.showLevels(1,0)
def showLevels(self, rowlevel, collevel):
    self.e.ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(rowlevel,collevel)
```

This works for collapsing rows. When i try e.showLevels(0,1) f.e. it doesn't work. Also when i only do this at the end of the grouping:

```
e.e.ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,0) //works for rows
e.e.ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,1) //works ONLY for rows. Not columns.
e.e.ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(0,1) //rows = 0 so not showing. Still columns not working
```

Simple said i can fold rows but i can't fold columns. Anybody has an idea how to make this work for the columns?

**EDIT: e.e. and self.e reference to the Excel workbook. ActiveSheet references to the current sheet.**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is `e`? What library are you using for accessing Excel files?

Comment: Sorry i will edit it. See the e.e. And the self.e as reference to the Excel workbook with ActiveSheet as reference to the current Sheet.

Comment: And what library are you using for accessing Excel files?

Comment: I communicate with Excel via a win32com client. But does that  have anything to do with grouping?

Comment: Yes, because I know a fair amount about `xlrd`, but sadly nothing about `win32com`. Sorry!

Comment: But its a call to a Excel function. Not an win32 function. This has nothing to do with win32.

Answer (score 0):

```
wksht.Outline.ShowLevels(ColumnLevels = 1)
```

The above worked for me. Maybe things have changed since this question was asked? Note: This command was undone when I did AutoFit() command on the grouped columns.

Answer (score 0):

MavenACTG's line of code worked for me as well.
Here is the modification for that code in xlwings:

```
worksheet.api.Outline.ShowLevels(RowLevels = 2, ColumnLevels = 1).
```